# 301 Redirect Problems

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a url structure that is passed through as following

```
www.mysite.com/path1/path2/pageA.html - www.mysite.com/newpath/pageA.html
www.mysite.com/path1/path2/path3/pageB.html - www.mysite.com/newpath/path3/pageB.html
www.mysite.com/path1/pageC.html - www.mysite.com/newpath/pageC.html
```

I have made the changes for the pass through like this and it is working

```
RewriteRule ^/newpath/(.*) /path1/path2/$1 [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^/newpath/(.*) /path1/$1 [PT,L]
```

I have also made changes in code to have the new URL's in pages except for some pages where we need 301 redirects to the new structure

Actual Location

```
www.mysite.com/path1/path2/pageA.html
www.mysite.com/path1/path2/path3/pageB.html
```

URL path in hyperlinks that have to be 301 redirected to Final Path URL

```
www.mysite.com/newpath/path2/pageA.html
www.mysite.com/newpath/path3/pageB.html
```

Final URL Path

```
www.mysite.com/newpath/pageA.html
www.mysite.com/newpath/path3/pageB.html
```

I am not able to create 301 redirects with the current pass through changes present as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove leading slash from URI matching pattern in .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^newpath/(.+)$ /path1/$1 [NC,L]
```